# Call Javascript function defined inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to call javascript function (on click()) which is inside Iframe

```
<a onclick="abc();" href=# >Call Function which is inside Iframe </a>

<iframe id=myFrame>
   <script>
     function abc(){
         alert("I am inside Iframe");
     }
    </script>
</iframe>
```

It will be better if there is solution in JQuery.

Thank you

Comment: why is it "better if there is solution in JQuery"?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251420/invoking-javascript-code-in-an-iframe-from-the-parent-page?rq=1

Answer (score 35):

You can do that this way:

```
<a onclick="$('#myFrame')[0].contentWindow.abc();">Call function which is inside of Iframe</a>
```

Basically, I get a reference to the Iframe. contentWindow is the global (window) object for the iframe, and all global functions in a document are methods of window.

As a note, you can only do this if both pages, the one containing the iframe and the one in the iframe come from the same domain.

Answer (score 27):

Use this to access your frame function:

```
    document.getElementById('myFrame').contentWindow.abc()
```

Comment: +1 for not having to mixed jQuery when not needed.

Answer (score 2):

You could also give the iframe a name='frameName', and then reference from the parent like this:
onclick="window.frameName.abc()"

Comment: doesn't work on chrome.